# How do I get the Android tablet emulator to be right-side up?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just downloaded the Android 3.0 SDK and booted up an emulator with it.  I rotated the emulator to portrait mode with Ctrl-F12 and then opened and the activity that was build with 2.2 and the whole emulator is upside down ( as in the emulator is upside down, home buttons are on the top and screen is upside down) .  Is there a way to rotate it the other way or am I missing something entirely?  ( I have already tried doing Ctrl-F11 or the Num pad, same result)

Comment: It's been about a month. Ever figure this out by any chance? I went all the way to page 3 on Google (didn't know if the internet would explode so I didn't go any further).

Comment: im having the same issue, that stuff with the screen orientation sensor portrait did not fix my issue.  if anyone figures this out please let me know...

Comment: what if you remove `screenOrientation` for activity from `manifest`

Answer (score 10):

open your androidmanifest file. In the application tab select an activity. Then scroll down to screen orientation and select sensorPortait in the drop-down menu. It's only available from api-level 9 (2.3.1) and higher.

[image]

Comment: no.  The activity already has the android:screenOrientation to "portrait" and I am looking for a solution that will handle 2.2

Comment: This helped me with android 4.0.3 tablet emulator. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem in the emulator (worked normally on the actual device).  It was fixed by changing android:screenOrientation="portrait" to android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" in my manifest for each Activity.  I just preferred to edit the XML directly instead of use the GUI, but it's the same fix as this answer gives.

Answer (score 1):

Well , there can be one of the 2 cases ,

1 - I misinterpreted your question , in which case i am extremely sorry

2 - The problem has been solved in the latest download of the android 3.0 Sdk(i just downloaded 1 right now )

Here , i am posting the screen shot of my AVD running 3.0 and a 2.2 Hello World Activity . 
[image]

[image]

[image: ps - I had changed my laptop to portrait more for this particular screen shot]

Comment: i believe you are interpreting my question correctly, however it may be something related to my project as i deleted the 3.0 AVD and downloaded the new one and still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple Demo project and trying it out ??

Comment: yes it does it with every project i try, even simple ones like hello world.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when I was forcing portrait by setting screen orientation to "portrait" in the manifest file. When I made my app support rotation, and switched screen orientation back to "unspecified" the issue went away.

If you don't want to support rotation, just change the manifest while you test, and before you open the app, rotate the emulator so it opens in portrait.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem on running the Android SDK (Eclipse) on an Intel (Core i5) Mac. I was able to fix it by disabling the "Use Host GPU" option for the AVD.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case when I rotated the emulator to portrait, the "desktop" would show correct. However the app would run upside down.

(This worked for v4 Ice Cream)
So, in portrait mode, in the bottom right corner of the emulator, select the settings and set "Auto-rotate screen" to OFF.
Run the app now and it will show correct.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the emulator targets like 4.4 (API level 19) and 2.3 have a bug. Change your emulator to target version 4.2 or 4.3 and try to change the orientation or try to disable hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing just happened to me with a KitKat emulator whenever I setup the AVD with a default orientation of Landscape. Switching the default to Portrait fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to tackle that problem is to just flip the display of your host system.
On the Mac you can do this in `System Preferences > Display` on Windows there is a keyboard shortcut: `ctrl + alt + arrow key`. (see here: https://superuser.com/questions/554589/how-can-i-horizontally-flip-invert-my-monitor-not-rotate and here: http://osxdaily.com/2010/12/28/rotate-mac-screen-orientation/)

And if you have a standalone trackpad you can just turn it around physically to have your mouse pointer move naturally.