# my android emulator is upside down with honeycomb, how can i correct this?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the Android tablet emulator to be right-side up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165181/how-do-i-get-the-android-tablet-emulator-to-be-right-side-up)

I have this issue with both the 3.0 and 3.1 SDK, when I test my activity that was built with 2.3.1, it is upside down. The entire menu, all the buttons, my app everything, when I hit CTRL+F12 it rotates 90 degrees fine, but then I do that again and it goes back to upside down again, how can I correct this to right side up?

Comment: Any progress on this one?  I have the same exact issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me was I Updated SDK Tools and ADT revision 17.

Answer (score 0):

Try CTRL+F11 for changing it to otherside

Comment: No, that only rotates it 90 degrees, and back, not 180